# Hadoop word count example - null pointer exception

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I'm Hadoop beginner. My setup: RHEL7, hadoop-2.7.3

I'm trying to run the [Example:_WordCount_v2.0](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v2.0). I just copied the source code to new eclipse project and export it to wc.jar file.

Now, I've configured hadoop [Pseudo-Distributed Operation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation) as explianed in the link. Then I start by the following:

creating input files in input directory:

```
echo "Hello World, Bye World!" > input/file01
echo "Hello Hadoop, Goodbye to hadoop." > input/file02
```

start env:

```
sbin/start-dfs.sh
bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/<username>
bin/hdfs dfs -put input input
bin/hadoop jar ws.jar WordCount2 input output
```

and this is what I got:

```
16/09/02 13:15:01 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
16/09/02 13:15:01 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
16/09/02 13:15:01 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
16/09/02 13:15:01 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
16/09/02 13:15:01 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local455553963_0001
16/09/02 13:15:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
16/09/02 13:15:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local455553963_0001
16/09/02 13:15:01 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
16/09/02 13:15:01 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/09/02 13:15:01 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local455553963_0001_m_000000_0
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/aii/input/file02:0+33
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local455553963_0001_m_000001_0
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/aii/input/file01:0+24
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
16/09/02 13:15:02 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local455553963_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at WordCount2$TokenizerMapper.setup(WordCount2.java:47)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local455553963_0001 running in uber mode : false
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local455553963_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
16/09/02 13:15:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

No results (output) was given. Why did I get that exception?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Thanks to solutions suggested I've realized that there is a second try (in the wordCount example):

```
echo "\." > patterns.txt
echo "\," >> patterns.txt
echo "\!" >> patterns.txt
echo "to" >> patterns.txt
```

and then run:

```
bin/hadoop jar ws.jar WordCount2 -Dwordcount.case.sensitive=true input output -skip patterns.txt
```

and everything is work great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is occurring in the `setup()` method of the mapper. This wordcount example is a bit more advanced than usual and allows you to specify a file containing patterns the mapper will filter out. This file is added to the cache in the `main()` method, so that its available on every node for the mappers to open.

You can see the files being added to the cache in `main()`:

```
for (int i=0; i < remainingArgs.length; ++i) {
    if ("-skip".equals(remainingArgs[i])) {
        job.addCacheFile(new Path(remainingArgs[++i]).toUri());
        job.getConfiguration().setBoolean("wordcount.skip.patterns", true);
    } else {
        otherArgs.add(remainingArgs[i]);
    }
}
```

You aren't specifying the `-skip` option so it won't try and add anything. If a file is added you can see it sets `wordcount.skip.patterns` to `true`.

In the mappers `setup()` you have this code:

```
 @Override
 public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     conf = context.getConfiguration();
     caseSensitive = conf.getBoolean("wordcount.case.sensitive", true);
     if (conf.getBoolean("wordcount.skip.patterns", true)) {
         URI[] patternsURIs = Job.getInstance(conf).getCacheFiles();
         for (URI patternsURI : patternsURIs) {
             Path patternsPath = new Path(patternsURI.getPath());
             String patternsFileName = patternsPath.getName().toString();
             parseSkipFile(patternsFileName);
         }
     }
}
```

The problem is this check `conf.getBoolean("wordcount.skip.patterns", true)` defaults to `true` if its not set, and in your case it won't be. Thus `patternsURIs` or something around there (i dont have the line numbers) will be null.

So you can either change `wordcount.case.sensitive` to default to `false`, set it to `false` in the driver (main method) or provide a skip file to fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. You can see the EDIT in my question - I figure it out from your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be this part of your code:

```
 caseSensitive = conf.getBoolean("wordcount.case.sensitive", true);
 if (conf.getBoolean("wordcount.skip.patterns", true)) {
     URI[] patternsURIs = Job.getInstance(conf).getCacheFiles();
     for (URI patternsURI : patternsURIs) {
         Path patternsPath = new Path(patternsURI.getPath());
         String patternsFileName = patternsPath.getName().toString();
         parseSkipFile(patternsFileName);
     }
 }
```

Here `getCacheFiles()` is returning `null` for any reason. That's why when you are trying to iterate over `patternsURIs` (which has nothing but `null`), you are getting exception.

To solve this, before starting loop check whether `patternsURIs` is null or not.

```
if(patternsURIs != null) {
    for (URI patternsURI : patternsURIs) {  
      Path patternsPath = new Path(patternsURI.getPath());
      String patternsFileName = patternsPath.getName().toString();
      parseSkipFile(patternsFileName);
    }
}
```

You should also check why are you getting `null`, if it is not expected to get `null`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this change, but I wanted to run the example before diving into the code. I'll keep you update. You can see the EDIT in my question - I figure it out :-)